# Prove that $\forall n \in \omega, n^+\nsubseteq n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $\forall n \in \omega, n^+\nsubseteq n$, where $\omega = \mathbb {N}$.

I have already proved that $\forall n \in \omega, n\not= n^+$.  I believe there should be an easy conclusion, but I'm not sure how to go about it formally.

Comment: $$n\subseteq n\cup\{n\}=n^+~\textrm{ but }~n\neq n^+~\textrm{ so }~n\subset n^+~\textrm{ ergo }~n^+\subsetneq n$$

Comment: Edit to the last comment: It should be $\not\subseteq$ instead of $\subsetneq$

Comment: By the definition of $\omega$, if $n\in \omega$ then $n$ is an ordinal. An ordinal is, by def'n, a transitive set on which $\in$ is a well-order.  But for $any$ ordinal $x$ we have $x\not \in x$ (regardless of Foundation). Because if $x\in x$ then $x=y$ for some $y\in x,$ and a well-order is by def'n irreflexive, so $\forall y \in x\,(y\not \in y).$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n^{+} \subseteq n$: in particular, $n \in n$, which is a contradiction due to the Axiom of Regularity.

Comment: No good reason to use regularity here.

Comment: I mean, it's a quick way of justifying the contradiction. I suppose one could go for a more "minimal" (in terms of axioms used) proof, e.g. using properties of ordinals, but I don't see the problem here. It also makes the proof more readable for someone who hasn't really gotten that far in set theory.

Comment: The issue isn't really minimality, it's that regularity isn't a well-motivated axiom for naive set theory. If a person hasn't really gotten that far (i.e. they haven't learned about rank, the cumulative hierarchy and well-founded vs non-well-founded sets, etc) they shouldn't have regularity at their disposal. Using it here obscures the actual reason that this theorem is true, which *is* well-motivated by naive set theory.

Comment: Also, the 'real reason' really isn't any more difficult a proof, especially since they say they've already proved $n\ne n^+.$

Comment: (And since I've gotten into this argument before, I'll add that, contrary to a widespread misconception, the axiom of regularity has absolutely nothing to do with avoiding Russell's paradox... ZF is just as consistent without it, which has to be the case since adding axioms can only make a consistent theory inconsistent, never vice versa.  (Sorry if you know this already, but every time I've been down this road before the other person has had this misconception.))

Comment: I now see your point, which is absolutely valid. Thank you for the explanation!